# Найти два максимальных элемента массива

Tags: c#, .net

Создаю 2 массива одинакового размера. Рандомно заполняю первый, нахожу максимум среди этих элементов и забиваю во второй массив всем элементы за исключением arrOne.Max(). И все бы хорошо на экране, но на место исключенного максимума встает нуль, потому что размерность то у них, одинаковая. NO LINQ и NO list, еще до них не добрался.

```
class Data {

    static void Main() {

        // Шаг 1: Объявляю массивы, забиваю первый массив значениями
        Random rand = new Random();
        int val = rand.Next(2, 10);
        int[] arrOne = new int[val];
        int[] arrTwo = new int[val];

        for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++) {

            arrOne[x] = rand.Next(-100, 100);

        }

        // Шаг 2: Узнаем максимальный элемент в первом массиве и исключаем это значение во втором цикле

        Console.Write("Массив 1: ");
        foreach (int x in arrOne) Console.Write( x + " ");
        int max = arrOne.Max();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Максимальный элемент в массиве 1: " + max + "\n" + "Сформированный массив 2: ");

        for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++) {

            if (arrOne[x] != max) {

                arrTwo[x] = arrOne[x];
                Console.Write(arrTwo[x] + " ");

            }
        }
        Console.Write("\n" + "Массив 2:");
        foreach (int z in arrTwo) Console.Write(z + " "); // на место исключенного max ставится 0
        Console.WriteLine();


    }

}
```

Comment: в чем вопрос? почему `int` инициализируется нулем?

Comment: @slippyk я забиваю второй массив всеми значениями из первого массива, кроме максимального, соответственно во втором массиве становится на один элемент меньше и встает нуль по умолчанию. Как отредактировать код, чтобы размерность второго массива изначально была -1 элемент.  `int[] arrTwo = new int[val - 1];` не выходит

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, суть то проблемы все-таки к чему сводиться, как получить 2 максимальных элемента в массиве или как изменить размерность второго массива?

Comment: @sp7 изменить размерность второго массива на -1

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev ответил вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто отсортировать массив входящий данных и потом выбрать два крайних элемента. Как вариант

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static int[] Sort(int[] ar)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<ar.Length-1;i++)
            {
                int min = i;
                for(int j = i+1;j<ar.Length;j++)
                    if(ar[j]<ar[min])
                        min = j;
                int temp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[min];
                ar[min] = temp;
            }

            return ar;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int val = rand.Next(2, 10);
            int[] arr = new int[val];
            for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
            {
                arr[x] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            }

            arr = Sort(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", arr[arr.Length-2], arr[arr.Length-1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не могу разобраться, можно чуть чуть псевдокода пожалуйста

Comment: Алгоритм Sort это обычный алгоритм сортировки выбором. Суть в том, что на каждом шаге ты выбираешь минимальный элемент из оставшихся(неотсортированных) и ставишь его на нужное место. В результате функция возвращает отсортированный массив и можно получить максимальный элемент, он будет в конце отсортированного массива и следующий после него

Comment: Почему `i<ar.Length-1` ? Почему -1 ?

Comment: Потому что на последней итерации у нас остается только один не отсортированный элемент, который в результате и так стоит на своем месте уже, можно добавить еще одну итерацию, но так как j идет от i+1 до длинны массива - 1, то на этой итерации ничего не произойдет

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста вот этот участок `int temp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[min];
                ar[min] = temp;`

Comment: В этих строках элементы массива меняются местами. Минимальный элемент среди отсортированных становится на свое место

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы уменьшить размерность второго массива на 1

```
 int[] arrTwo = new int[val - 1];
```

И теперь измени немного заполнение второго массива, для второго массива был свой индексатор, который с того момента как будет пройден максимальный элемент будет на 1 меньше, чем индексатор первого массива

```
        var index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++)
        {                
            if (arrOne[x] == max)
            {
                index = x - 1;
                continue;
            }
            index = index < x ? x - 1 : x;

            arrTwo[index] = arrOne[x];
            Console.Write(arrTwo[index] + " ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Что бы изменить размер массива нужно использовать метод `Array.Resize`.

```
int[] array = { 50, 10, -1, 50, 5, 6 };

// Смотрим что бы значение нового массива не было меньше 0. 
if(array.Length - 1 >= 0)
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - 1);
```